# Checkstyle gradle use google checks

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I want to use google style checks with gradle checkstyle(v8.42) plugin.

Is google_checks.xml available in plugin or configuration should be copied from https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/checkstyle-8.42/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `google_checks.xml` is part of the published Checkstyle JAR:

[image: checkstyle JAR contents]

So you can use Gradle to retrieve the resource from the JAR.

The below will work. It is written in the Kotlin DSL, but can easily translated to the Groovy DSL.

```
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("checkstyle")
}

checkstyle {
    val archive = configurations.checkstyle.get().resolve().filter {
        it.name.startsWith("checkstyle")
    }
    config = resources.text.fromArchiveEntry(archive, "google_checks.xml")
}
```